# Angle Reflexion for bouncing ball in a circle

Tags: python, pygame, geometry, angle, bounce

I am making a game with some bouncing elements IN a circle (I use pygame) ,
My elements have 2 attributes  , one for the angle and one for the speed
Here is how elements moves :

```
mvx = math.sin(self.angle) * self.speed  
mvy = -math.cos(self.angle) * self.speed  
self.x += mvx  
self.y += mvy
```

My problem is this : I know the angle at the top (99.6°) , I have the collision point (x and y ) , but I'm unable to find the angle at the bottom(42.27°)
Does someones can make a relation between the first angle and the second ?

Picture is better ...
[image]

Comment: what about just `a1 = a2 + a3`? `a1 = 42.27 + 28.85*2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend do calculate the [reflection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_(mathematics)) vector to the incident vector on the circular surface.
In the following formula `N` is the normal vector of the circle, `I` is the incident vector (the current direction vector of the bouncing ball) and `R` is the reflection vector (outgoing direction vector of the bouncing ball):

```
R = I - 2.0 * dot(N, I) * N.
```

Use the [`pygame.math.Vector2`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/math.html#pygame.math.Vector2.normalize).

To calculate the normal vector, you' ve to know the "hit" point (`dvx`, `dvy`) and the center point of the circle (`cptx`, `cpty`):

```py
circN = (pygame.math.Vector2(cptx - px, cpty - py)).normalize()
```

Calculate the reflection:

```py
vecR = vecI - 2 * circN.dot(vecI) * circN
```

The new angle can be calculated by [`math.atan2(y, x)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html):

```
self.angle  = math.atan2(vecR[1], vecR[0])
```

Code listing:

```py
import math
import pygame
```

```py
px = [...] # x coordinate of the "hit" point on the circle
py = [...] # y coordinate of the "hit" point on the circle

cptx = [...] # x coordinate of the center point of the circle
cpty = [...] # y coordinate of the center point of the circle

circN = (pygame.math.Vector2(cptx - px, cpty - py)).normalize()
vecI  = pygame.math.Vector2(math.cos(self.angle), math.sin(self.angle))
vecR  = vecI - 2 * circN.dot(vecI) * circN

self.angle = math.pi + math.atan2(vecR[1], vecR[0])
```

Comment: Thank's a lot ! It works !
I just add PI to the last angle to change his direction 
    self.angle = math.pi + math.atan2(vecR[1], vecR[0])

Answer (score 0):

The inner angles of a triangle need to sum up to `180°`. Also, the angle `99.96°` is supplementary to the triangle's angle next to it (calling it by `A`), i.e. `99.96° + A = 180°` so `A = 180° - 99.96°`. Calling of `B = 42.27°` the bottom angle. And for the last angle `C`, we can use that it is opposed by the vertex with the other angle that is equal to `2 * 28.85 = 57.7°`.
Then:

```
A + B + C = 180°

180° - 99.96° + 42.27°  + 2 * 28.85° = 180°

180° - 99.96° + 42.27°  + 2 * 28.85° = 180°

-99.96° + 42.27°  + 2 * 28.85° = 0°

42.27°  + 2 * 28.85° = 99.96°

B + C = Top angle
```

P.S.: I know that the values are not exactly equal, but it must be because of the decimal places rounding